# Removing Carriage breaks and Line Breaks from a Column in multiple cells

Tags: excel, replace

**Trying to remove Carriage Returns and Line Breaks from a Column. Replaceing them with a "Period Space"**

**I was able to Find and Replace using one of these codes (ALT + 0010) and (Alt + 0013) and (CTRL + J). I replaced them with (. ) so the descriptions look nice still.**

**Here is the original Text that i filtered page breaks and line breaks from**

```
    "MS-01 Our MS series are some of the best student microscopes on the 
    market today. With extra features such as the rotatable head, fine focus 
    control, and the option to add the mechanical stage, these scopes are a 
    popular choice for educational use. Detailed description: Quality metal 
    contruction, with optics and conforming to the universal standards (DIN) 
    for microscopes, and 5 year warranty makes these reliable microscopes 
    for a great value.   Features:
    10X Eyepiece with scale pointer
    Monocular head rotatable 360°
    3 DIN Achromatic parfocal and parcentered Objectives 4X, 10X, & 40XR
    Total magnification 40X to 400X
    Coaxial coarse & fine focusing
    Disc Diaphragm
    20W lamp
    Vinyl dust cover, spare bulb."
```

**After Doing to Filter for Breaks and Lines and replacing them with (. ) I turned it into this**

```
    MS-01 Our MS series are some of the best student microscopes on the                 
    market today. With extra features such as the rotatable head, fine focus 
    control, and the option to add the mechanical stage, these scopes are a 
    popular choice for educational use. Detailed description: Quality metal 
    contruction, with optics and conforming to the universal standards (DIN) 
    for microscopes, and 5 year warranty makes these reliable microscopes 
    for a great value. Features:. . 10X Eyepiece with scale pointer. 
    Monocular head rotatable 360°. 3 DIN Achromatic parfocal and parcentered 
    Objectives 4X, 10X, & 40XR. Total magnification 40X to 400X. Coaxial 
    coarse & fine focusing. Disc Diaphragm. 20W lamp. Vinyl dust cover, 
    spare bulb.
```

Now, When I Copy this New Cell and Paste into the Formula Bar on the same cell, it just turns back to normal. I don't know what i'm doing wrong that its not actually changing the format of these returns.

Also when I try to remove the instance of (. .) or (..) or (:.) after i replace using one of the above Alt Codes, it doesn't even find these values. The space that is in between the periods takes 2 deletes to get rid of which is odd.

I am looking for the best way to remove these breaks from this document.
Tried tackling if for two days now.

You can find the Document at - **http://www.yopmail.com/en/** 
using the email address - **Helpdannyhagstromout.yopmail.com**

Comment: You're certain your text isn't wrapping to the next line in the formula? Since nobody has replied in half an hour, I think you might want to simplify your question or give some illustrative examples. Seems like your issue should be easy to solve. Give a little more specific detail to illustrate and someone can probably help you.

Comment: You ever get this figured out? Screen shots aren't an option? If you want to send an example or screen shot email it to: `HelpDannyHagstromOut@yopmail.com` . This is an email address that anyone can access, so consider whatever you send it being like posting to a website. Comment back if you send as I obviously don't check that address.

Comment: **This was never solved**

Comment: Sorry @Danny Hagstrom. Most questions do get answered but the community (myself included) didn't have enough information to get a solution for you. I do know that's frustrating so don't take it personal, we all work for somewhat meaningless "points" so if it's not too obvious what's wrong, we tend to lose interest. I didn't see anything in the email address, did you send your example? You also might consider visiting a contracting website. Google "quick excel help" or something and I'll bet you could find someone eager to help for less than $25. I hope that helps you out. Best of luck.